# How do i create a live store locator using Google Maps in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I want to create a google map api, whereby when a user opens my asp.net website page, they would be shown the nearest supermarkets in their area.

I currently only have this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jssensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
                var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: LatLng,
                    zoom: 13,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: LatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    infoWindow.setContent(marker.title);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            });
        } else {
            alert('Geo Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
        }
    </script>
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAmP-KSUXWojDj8Cg38zkYI3B0eRCKquvQ&callback=initMap"
      type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
    </div>
```

It currently only displays my location using geolocation, but I want to add a function to show the nearest supermarkets in the located area.

Hopefully someone is able to help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Coles or Woolies?

Comment: I am intending to use it to locate supermarkets in Singapore... :)